# how to find length of response list in python using request

Tags: python, json, parsing, request

I'm using request library for parsing data, it returning list of json data 
when im trying to find the length  of response list it giving error 
**TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()**
im using this method

```
  import requests
r=requests.get('http://localhost:3000/api/Customer')
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)

x={}
for i in range(0,len(r)):
    x = r.json()[i]
    print(x)
```

by using this im getting error
**TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `len` on the list object returned by `r.json()` instead:

```
lst = r.json()
for i in range(len(lst)):
    x = lst[i]
    print(x)
```

But then you should simply iterate over the list instead:

```
for x in r.json():
    print(x)
```